# React Redux Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-redux

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion con React + Redux + React Router Dom

Tengo las rutas definidas usando createBrowserRouter

En mi archivo Index tengo el siguiente bloque de codigo:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { RouterProvider } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { router } from './routes/routes';
import { store } from './app/store';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RouterProvider router={router}/>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

El Provider store={store} es de redux para poder utilizar el estado de la aplicacion.
y dentro de el tengo el RouterProvider  de React Router Dom para poder navegar en mi app.

pero esto me da el siguiente error en tiempo de ejecucion:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
```

Comment: En algun lugar de tu código estas tratando de usar `useContext` pero no esta disponible por alguna razón y me parece que en esta pieza de código que compartes no se ve declarado ni nada, busca donde esta y comparte ese componente

Comment: El useContext me indica que es dentro de un archivo propio de redux

Comment: Comparte el componente store